# JS code works if launched in webView using loadUrl() but not evaluateJavascript()

Tags: javascript, android, android-webview

I need to play video in `html5` `video` tag in Android webView. 
I used android method

> webView.loadUrl("javascript:" + url);

previously, but decided replace it with modern method

> webView.evaluateJavascript(url, null);

And I faced on issue with `evaluateJavascript()` method:

> "Failed to execute 'play' on 'HTMLMediaElement': API can only be
>   initiated by a user gesture."

But with `loadUrl()` this issue was not fired.
How to play video using `evaluateJavascript()` and html video tag?

Comment: why? if it works with the other method use the other method. what is the real problem?

Comment: @Pamblam evaluateJavascript() allows to get result which return JS code. loadUrl() does not allow this.

Comment: use a [JavascriptInterface](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/JavascriptInterface.html) to allow your webview JS to communicate with host App..

Comment: @Pamblam `JavascriptInterface` allow to call Java methods from JS side. I need vice versa - call JS methods from Java side.

Answer (score 1):

on the webview try this, should work after this:

myWebView.getSettings().setMediaPlaybackRequiresUserGesture(false);